# The BVP $x \phi_x - 2 \phi_y = 0$, $\phi_x(x,0) = x \cos(x^2)$, $x > 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> Solve the following homogeneous first order PDEs subject to the given boundary
>   condition:
>
> $$x\phi_{x}-2\phi_{y}=0, \quad \phi_{x}(x,0)=x\cos(x^2), \quad x>0$$

My attempt using method of characteristic:
Integrating $\frac{dx}{x}= \frac{dy}{-2}$ on both sides gives $y=-2\ln x+\alpha$.
The characteristic curve is  now given: $\zeta = y+2\ln x$.
I know  that $\phi(x,y)$ is a function $f(\zeta)$ but I don't know how to apply the boundary condition.
Would appreciate anyone who can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The *family* of characteristic curves is indeed
$$
y+2\ln(x)=C, \quad (C \in \mathbf R),
$$
and the main staterment of the method of characteristics for first-order semilinear equations implies then that the general solutution is
$$
\varphi(x,y)=F(y+2\ln(x))
$$
where $F$ is a continuously differentiable function (I'd recommend my [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MZ1LDYS) on PDEs to consult the version of the method of characteristics for f.-o. semilinear equations). Now to solve the boundary value problem you've got to find out what a/the function $F$ above is.

Deduce from your boundary conditions that
$$
F(2 \ln(x))=\frac{\sin(x^2)}2+C
$$
and then that
$$
F(x)=\frac{\sin(e^x)}2+C.
$$
Then you'll get the family of solutions 
$$
\phi(x,y)= \frac{\sin(e^y x^2)}2+C
$$
satisfying the problem in question.